# Invoking method by reflection returns inconsistent results if the class is compiled more than once during run time

Tags: java, reflection

I compile a class during runtime and then later call that classes methods. If the class was compiled more than once the boolean methods always return true instead of the response appropriate to the arguments.

The weird part is that when I debug, I can see that the compiled class is the same and correct, the correct method at the correct class path is found and the arguments are the same.

Method that compiles the code:

```
public static void compile(String conditionClass){
    try {
        String fullPath =  getClassPath() + "/" + target;

        File file = new File(fullPath + ".java");
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();
        file.createNewFile();

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
        pw.print(conditionClass);
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();

        JavaCompiler javac = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        String[] methodArgs = {fullPath + ".java"};
        javac.run(null, null, null, methodArgs);

        targetClass = Class.forName(target);

        file.delete();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static String getClassPath() throws Exception {
    for (String s : System.getProperty("java.class.path").split(":"))
        if (s.indexOf("/target/classes") + "/target/classes".length() == s.length())
            return s;
}
```

Method that calls the code:

```
public boolean call(String methodName, String[][][] arg1, String[] arg2){
    try {
        Method m = targetClass.getMethod(methodName, new Class[]{String[][][].class, String[].class});
        Object[] args = new Object[]{arg1, arg2};
        Object response = m.invoke(null, args);
        return (boolean)response;
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return true;
}
```

The class that's being compiled details:
class body, which gets passed as conditionClass:

```
public class TestClass{
    public static boolean method1(String[][][] arg1, String[] arg2){
        boolean res = true;

        if(path[0][0][0].equals("test target"))
            return false;

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you compile that class during runtime?

Comment: The classloader caches classes once loaded (it doesn't reload them from disk every time). Are you doing anything to handle that? I don't see any code that looks like it does, but it's not an area I've really gotten into...

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the compiled class. So it would be interesting which class/method you intend to compile/call.

Comment: Please post the class that gets compiled

Comment: ^^ ...both before and after the change. E.g., please your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem that we can copy and paste and run to replicate the problem and help you solve it.

Comment: I suspect that the second call runs in to the exception causing your method to return true. Yet this means that the error is not in the posted code. So update how you invoke `call`, best post the whole programm. And replace your stacktrace printing by exception rethrowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by T.J. Crowder the problem was that the class with the same path and name won't be loaded again.

For my task simply changing the name of the class and reloading it to the JVM was enough, but it's a crud approach non the less and should be avoided.